# Can I add new fields in a Class using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

Can I add a new field to a class if I have its class literal object and how can I determine that a particular Class is referenced or used in that class literal ?

Comment: What purpose would it solve to do these things? They may be good academic exercises, but they're almost always poor decisions when it comes to production code.

Comment: glowcoder@you are right,but when you write  your own class loaders and if you want to check that the classes your class loader is loading should not violate certain conditions like using some unauthorized code,then how will you do it

Comment: Again, what problem does writing your own class loader solve? I mean, who would have access to the production system to put unauthorized code there in the first place?

Comment: @corsiKa Maybe you are right. After all it's Java. Maybe I should switch to a real language for the 'production' code I am aiming for.

Comment: @atas I'm not sure what you mean. As of August 2013, there are more Java programmers than any other language (although it fluctuates a lot, Java is usually very near the top.) I'm not sure if being the most widely used programming language counts as a 'real' language, but there are literally millions of servers running Java in production. So I'm really confused at your comment.

Comment: @corsiKa I didn't mean to be disrespectful towards Java. I am using Java myself, although not entirely by personal choice (maybe because of "As of August 2013, there are more Java programmers than any other language")... Anyway, see my answer to the question and try to think of a language that supports this without some external heavyweight library with bloated terms such as "marshaling"; that is generating types and code dynamically as part of the language itself.

Comment: @atas I think most programmers would say that adding members to a class at runtime is a bad idea, which is why its hard to do in Java. If you really needed this kind of functionality, there's always Map,

Comment: I had to come back here to write that what I was looking for is actually in the JVM: at least Groovy metaprogramming and also Scala.

Answer (score 6):

You can't directly add a new field to the `Class` object.  There are third-party APIs that you can use to do class generation or modification (e.g. ASM, BCEL), though they're best avoided because they add a lot of complexity.

As for the second part of your question, you can use the `Class` object to go through the fields and examine them.

```
// NOTE : this only looks at the fields in A and not it's superclass.
//        you'll have to do a recursive lookup if you want super's fields too.
for(Field field : A.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
    if(B.class.equals(field.getType()) {
        System.out.println("A." + field.getName() + " is of type B");
    }
}
```

Comment: thnx and what about examining the class for a particular class reference,like is it possible that I can know wheather a Class A is using a reference of Class B

Comment: I'm not sure I follow...do you mean like how to see if Class A has any fields or methods that refer to Class B?

Comment: But what if I am creating Class B referance in some method ?like void create() { class B = new B() }

Comment: Ha...that's beyond me.  You'd have to decompile the code...maybe look into those bytecode manipulation libraries that I mentioned (ASM, BCEL)?

Answer (score 2):

You don't state what you need this feature for, but maybe you'd like to consider JAXB if you want to stick to Java: you declare your Java class as XML and it is generated dynamically. Maybe that helps.