# Dynamically adding variables to JavaBean

Tags: java

Is there a way to build a JavaBean dynamically based on the DB table column names and assoicated data? For example, if I get back of 5 columns in a db table, I need to create a javaBean with those 5 column names as variables and their getters/setters as well. Next time, if I get 7 columns, I can create a javaBean with 7 variables.

Comment: your means is: Java beans automatically synchronized with database tables?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can do this with byte code manipulation.

2 main libraries are:

- javassist - http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/
- asm - http://asm.ow2.org/

Comment: This  is best solution but very complex;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can have an object with variable fields, but you could use a Map to store the results. That might be the closest to what you want.

Comment: Thanks Eivind.I want this thing to be done without use of map ..
I want to send these bean Objects to Adobe Flex framework

Comment: You can look at this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431664/can-i-add-new-fields-in-a-class-using-reflection) answer to a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

Well it doesn't have to be a "dynamic" bean, you can just use a Map variant, like `HashMap`. Nothing wrong with that.

```
Map<String,Object> results = new HashMap<String,Object>();
// .. fill results ...
// .. then
Object someData = results.get("someDataKey");
```

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is no. You cannot ask for variables at run time. What you can do is.

```
Map<String, Map> results = new HashMap<String, Map>();
// Associate each column with a new map and put it in results.
// Take each variable from column and associate it with the corresponding column's hashmap.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement [the `org.apache.commons.beanutils.DynaBean` interface](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/DynaBean.html):

> A `DynaBean` is a Java object that supports properties whose names and
> data types, as well as values, may be dynamically modified. **To the
> maximum degree feasible, other components of the BeanUtils package**
> will recognize such beans and treat them as standard JavaBeans for the
> purpose of retrieving and setting property values.